# HTTP vs JDBC on Jetty server

Tags: rest, jdbc, jetty

I have a Jetty server running a few apis over HTTP/s. I have a 3rd party client that wants to connect to my REST service using a jdbc connection. I am not sure how that will work in a Jetty server.

Can I get some pointers on how do I figure this out?

Comment: You cannot connect to a REST service (HTTP/S) using JDBC. Different protocols, different technologies, different purposes. You _might_ be able to provide database views which contain the _equivalent_ data as provided by your REST service - and you _could_ lock down access to those views... But personally, I would never hand over any database credentials for my database to a 3rd party (and give them network access?), so I would never recommend doing that. What to do instead? That depends on _why_ your client wants to do what they want to do. That's probably out of scope for SO.

Comment: As @andrewJames says, JDBC to REST is not a thing that exists, anywhere, in any software.